# Using Context from Documents in LangChain ConversationalRetrievalChain

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, langchain, large-language-model

I am working with the LangChain library in Python to build a conversational AI that selects the best candidates based on their resumes. The process involves using a `ConversationalRetrievalChain` to handle user queries. My chain needs to consider the context from a set of documents (resumes) for its decision-making process.

Here is how I initialize my chain:

```py
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain.prompts.prompt import PromptTemplate

# Template setup
template = """
You are HR assistant to select best candidates based on the resume based on the user input. It is important to return resume ID when you find the promising resume. Start with AAAAAAAAAAAAA
Here is context including list of resume information: {context}
user input: {question} 
AI Assistant: start with AAAAAAAAAAAAA
[/INST]"""
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["question", "context"], template=template)

# Chain initialization
conversation_chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm=llm,
    retriever=db.as_retriever(search_kwargs={'k': 4}),
    condense_question_prompt = PROMPT,
)
```

The first query works fine:

```py
chat_history = []
query = "which resume is best for senior HR position, return ID"
result = conversation_chain({"question": query, "chat_history": chat_history})
```

However, when I run a subsequent query, I receive an error:

```py
chat_history = [(query, result["answer"])]
query = "what is its ID number"
result = conversation_chain({"question": query, "chat_history": chat_history})
```

**Error:**

```
ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'context'}
```

How can I correctly use the context from documents (resumes) for subsequent queries in the `ConversationalRetrievalChain`? I assume the issue is with how I'm passing the context in the second query, but I'm not sure how to properly maintain or update the context for ongoing conversation. Any guidance or examples on how to manage this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

in your tempplate, you have `context`:

```
template = """
You are HR assistant to select best candidates based on the resume based on the user input. It is important to return resume ID when you find the promising resume. Start with AAAAAAAAAAAAA
Here is context including list of resume information: {context}
user input: {question} 
AI Assistant: start with AAAAAAAAAAAAA
[/INST]"""
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["question", "context"], template=template)
```

you even mentioned in `PromptTemplate` but when you call the chain, you did not pass `context`

```
result = conversation_chain({"question": query, "chat_history": chat_history})
```

Comment: how can i pass the context which is retrieved data from db? Should I use similarity search for bd (which is a vector database)?